# Elasticsearch indexing fails after successful Nutch crawl

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I'm not sure why but Nutch 1.13 is failing to index the data to ES (v2.3.3). It is crawling, that is fine, but when it comes time to index to ES its giving me this error message:

```
Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)
```

Right before that is has this:

```
elastic.bulk.close.timeout : elastic timeout for the last bulk in seconds. (default 600)
```

I'm not sure exactly if the timeout has anything to do with the job failing?

I've run Nutch v1.10 many times with no problems but decided to upgrade now. Never had this error before until now, with upgrading.

**EDIT:**
After closer inspection of the error message:

```
    Error running:
  /home/david/tutorials/nutch/nutch-1.13/runtime/local/bin/nutch index -Delastic.server.url=http://localhost:9300/search-index/ searchcrawl//crawldb -linkdb searchcrawl//linkdb searchcrawl//segments/20170519125546
```

It seems to be failing there, on that particular segment, what does that mean? I only know the basics of how to use Nutch, I'm by no means an expert. Is it failing on a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Nutch 1.14 is out, you need to apply this patch https://github.com/apache/nutch/pull/156 and rebuild:

```
cd apache-nutch-1.13
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/nutch/e040ace189aa0379b998c8852a09c1a1a2308d82/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/CleaningJob.java
mv CleaningJob.java  src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/.
```

Comment: thanks man, I did it but the indexing still isn't working. However, I think the problem is 2 fold. This issue and a guava dependency issue with ES.