# Error indexing Nutch crawl data into Elasticsearch

Tags: nutch, elasticsearch-5

I'm using Nutch 1.14 and trying to index a small web crawl into ES v5.3.0 and I keep getting this error:

```
ElasticIndexWriter
    elastic.cluster : elastic prefix cluster
    elastic.host : hostname
    elastic.port : port
    elastic.index : elastic index command 
    elastic.max.bulk.docs : elastic bulk index doc counts. (default 250)
    elastic.max.bulk.size : elastic bulk index length in bytes. (default 2500500)
    elastic.exponential.backoff.millis : elastic bulk exponential backoff initial delay in milliseconds. (default 100)
    elastic.exponential.backoff.retries : elastic bulk exponential backoff max retries. (default 10)
    elastic.bulk.close.timeout : elastic timeout for the last bulk in seconds. (default 600)


Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)

Error running:
  /home/david/tutorials/nutch/apache-nutch-1.14-src/runtime/local/bin/nutch index -Delastic.server.url=http://localhost:9300/search-index/ searchcrawl//crawldb -linkdb searchcrawl//linkdb searchcrawl//segments/20180824175802
Failed with exit value 255.
```

I've already done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074819/elasticsearch-indexing-fails-after-successful-nutch-crawl) and I still get the error...

**UPDATE** - Ok, I've made progress. Indexing seems to work now - no more errors. However, when I go to see use _stats via Kibana to check the document count I get 0 when Nutch is telling me this:

```
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20180830115119.
Indexer: starting at 2018-08-30 12:19:31
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Active IndexWriters :
ElasticRestIndexWriter
    elastic.rest.host : hostname
    elastic.rest.port : port
    elastic.rest.index : elastic index command 
    elastic.rest.max.bulk.docs : elastic bulk index doc counts. (default 250) 
    elastic.rest.max.bulk.size : elastic bulk index length. (default 2500500 ~2.5MB)


Indexer: number of documents indexed, deleted, or skipped:
Indexer:      9  indexed (add/update)
Indexer: finished at 2018-08-30 12:19:45, elapsed: 00:00:14
```

I'm assuming that means ES was sent 9 documents for indexing?

Comment: Check the logs on the ES side, in this case, the only information that we can get is that the indexing failed.

Comment: @JorgeLuis - I've looked at the logs and it seems the TransportService was closed but I'm pretty sure my local ES was running. Has Elastic deprecated the TransportClient entirely?

Comment: Can you upload the logs to a Github gist or something? it should be more information there. Could it be that is timing out?

Comment: @JorgeLuis - sorry about the delay, here is a gist of the ES logs https://gist.github.com/redlinecodes/6fb77ca7e13d6785803b8fdfa7e8966d  - it looks like there might a memory issue??

Comment: @JorgeLuis - I've done lots of searching and on SO and Google to try and resolve this - you seem to be quite knowledgeable about Nutch (and ES integration). In your opinion, if I'm trying to update my vertical search engine - which version of Nutch would you use and would you also use the Jest REST api for ES integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Elasticsearch 6.0 with nutch 1.14 and it worked like a charm, I was using  **indexer-elastic-rest** plugin with port 9200, i am attaching the my [nutch-site.xml](https://github.com/iamhigh/nutch-plugins/blob/master/conf/nutch-site.xml) for the reference.

Comment: did you keep everything default with Jest and did you just use the cli crawl commands or did you have to use Nutch 1x REST api?

Comment: thanks. I'm going to start with a fresh 1.14 with fresh nutch-site.xml and go from there. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: please see my UPDATE above when you get a chance

Comment: Chadhary - Success! I upgraded to ES and Kibana 5.6.0 and I now see documents indexed to ES via Nutch! Must have needed to upgrade the whole time :) Thanks very much for your help.